# Do Directors of a company have automatic right to access that company's IP?

Tags: intellectual-property

If a company brings on a new director, are they obliged to share their IP with that new director?

And what about if they were to bring on a new shareholder — would they be obliged to share their IP?

Comment: The question should explain what "share" means (disclose? give rights to use? give ownership?) In any case, no and no.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I should have been clearer. I meant disclose — I suppose your answer holds, that the company is not obliged to disclose its IP to new directors?

Answer (score 0):

A company is not required to disclose its IP (copyrights, trademarks, trade secrets) to a director or a shareholder, nor to authorize such a person to use any of those, or any patents (patents of course must be publicly disclosed to everyone). In some cases a director might be unable to properly perform his or her function without some knowledge of company IP. In such a case, the director would probably be asked to sign a *non-disclosure agreement* (NDA) before being given access. Usually there would be no need for the director to be given al the details.

Trademarks are generally disclosed to the public when they are used, and copyrights are disclosed when and if the work is published, so the disclosure part applies most to trade secrets.